# Using WordPress functions on an external page

Tags: php, wordpress

So I need to grab some data from my main WordPress site and use it on an external page.

My WordPress site is located on the root of my domain while the external page is under /community/library/somethingelse/page.php

Anyway, I use the following code to get access to the function

```
<?php require('/path/to/my/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Using this gives me the following error when I try to access `page.php`

`This Plugin Requires WordPress 3.1+ or Greater: Activation Stopped!`

If someone has a possible solution for this, it would be great!

There are literally no answers that satisfy this question. If anyone could please figure out why this is happening and how to overcome it, it would be great. I still want to use WordPress functions and would not like to access the database directly.

Comment: What WordPress version are you using?

Comment: The latest, I believe 3.5.2

Comment: I guess there's a plugin that is causing that. Can you deactivate all plugin, switch to default theme and try again?

Comment: I am doing this on an external page... why would a plugin/theme be a problem?

Comment: Your whole WP will load when you run `wp-blog-header.php`

Comment: Shouldn't this cause a problem on my normal wordpress site as well then?

Comment: as long as you don't modify the files or the database, you shouldn't worry about your wp site.

Comment: Do you know how to extract data from a database? If so, connect and go to town. If memory serves correctly, there is file called `functions.php` or `core-functions.php`in the root or core directory. Include that and you can use wp functions

Comment: I think the solution is in the error message. Visit your WordPress dashboard and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens. It works as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing not too long ago, and it's hard to circumvent that warning without including a lot of "unnecessary" files into your project.

I'm saying "unnecessary" because you do need them, but it's just way too much just to pull some data to your application.

The way I did it, if possible in your environment, is to query the database directly, for example if you need access to the posts, then query `wp_posts` table.

If you need to pull posts per user, then you should be able to query the database directly. Security-wise you have to sanitize all output, for example using `htmlentities` in php.

Here's the database schema for the current version of PHP (it might be different for your version)

http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png

Something like:

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = 1`

should give you all the posts written by the admin user.

You can include wp_config.php to have access to your database credentials, and then connecting to your database using PDO (or mysqli) this way:

```
require('path/to/wp_config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT post_date, post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = ?";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_params("i", $user_id);
$statement->bind_result($post_date, $post_title, $post_content);
$user_id = 1;
$statement->execute();
while($statement->fetch() {
    echo "{$post_date}\n{$post_title}\n{$post_content}";
}
$statement->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

If you haven't used mysqli before, you can read more about it in these two links:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Also some posts may include bb tags, rich text, and a bunch of other different thing that Wordpress handles for you, but if you query the database directly you're going to have to whitelist HTML tags (like h1), and even write a BB code parser.

A good alternative is to create a blank Wordpress Template, and then include it in your application via iframes.

However, to pull that off you might have to create a duplicate of your wordpress blog with the same database configuration to have two templates active on the same blog. The "blank" template would be hidden from user view.

Another alternative is to write an RSS reader, but I'm not sure if it's possible to fetch RSS feed per user.

Comment: ahhh, never thought of it that way. I just need to pull some posts, for each user and display them on their profile pages. Wouldn't it be a little dangerous accessing the database directly, security wise? In any case, I don't have much experience with doing it that way. Can we run WP_Query and the parameters it comes with?

Comment: You just have to be careful when displaying users' posts on your website because some posts might contain html or script tags. Security wise you must sanitize all output, if you're using php you can use htmlentities to sanitize output.

Comment: regarding wp_query you should be able to run it, if you include all wp_core files... but then again it might be easier (not necessarily better) to query the database directly. It depends if you're ok with the overhead that you're going to cause by including wp core files.

Comment: I require the custom post meta field of a custom post type. I don't mind a little bit more overhead. I can easily do this through wp_query as long as you can put the solution on how to do that? I'm totally inexperienced with querying the database like you've done, and it wouldn't be right to ask you to give me a full solution and walk me through it.